# Handle expecting values getting privacy accounts from Instagram

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, instagram, instagram-api

I have a list of some instagram accounts and throught Instagram url '?__a=1' I'm trying to get the privacy of the account. Everything is fine, but after about 128 usernames, I get the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

that's my code

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from pandas import read_csv
import sqlite3

#connecting to database
db = sqlite3.connect('followers_check.db')
c = db.cursor()
cnt = 0

#path to followers name
file = '/Users/Desktop/followers_data/follower.csv'
list = pd.read_csv(file)
loop = list.iterrows()

for i in loop:
    cnt = cnt + 1
    if cnt>127:
        usm = (i[1]['names'])
        page_content = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/'+usm+'/?__a=1')
        tree = page_content.json()
        privacy_account = tree['graphql']['user']['is_private']

        if privacy_account==False:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO followers_checked(usm) VALUES (?)", [usm])
            db.commit()
            print('done...'+str(cnt))
```

anyone has a solution or any advice?

Comment: Initial guess is that you're being rate-limited as a bot attack. You should be checking the status code of your request, and try introducing some time.sleep into your code so you're not hitting as many connections as possible as fast as possible. Websites don't like that

Comment: Okay I guessed well. Do you think I could solve the problem setting a rotating Proxy Socks?

Comment: introducing some time intervals into your code _may_ help, rotating proxies _may_ help, there are many different things you can do to try to reduce the overall likelihood of being blocked, but that is too broad a question for  this site. Your best bet is to research and find a combination of tools and techniques that gives you what you need

Comment: Just another question. What do you think could be a right time-sleep? How many requests I have to do before doing a time sleep? Anyway thank you.

Comment: No way of knowing that, it's entirely based on the site. Generally a random choice between .5 and 2 seconds between each request has worked for me on some sites, but you'd have to test and see what works